# Why else if is used only one time here?

Tags: c

I don't understand a part of this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
main()
{
      int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

      state = OUT;
      nl = nw = nc = 0;
      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            ++nc;
            if (c == '\n')
               ++nl;
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
               state = OUT;
            else if (state == OUT) {
                 state = IN;
                 ++nw;
            }
            printf("char: %c %x | state: %d | word: %d\n", c, c, state, nw);
      }
      printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Why did they use "else if" only one time and not also for the second time?

Comment: let's turn this around: why do you **think** there should be an `else if` and what would happen on a newline (`\n`) character?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I don't know when I should use "if" and when "else if" tbh

Comment: Then it's time to grab some beginners' book (or other resource) and learn the language first. Stackoverflow isn't really suited for giving language tutorials.

Comment: It would be a good idea to stop omitting curly braces.

Comment: @VTT this is probably "old style code" from the days the size of the terminal mattered

Comment: @FelixPalmen It's a code from K&R, I'm learning from that book

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yeah, `int c, nl, nw, nc, state;` is definitely points that way.

Comment: You could read that as "if c isn't space, newline or tab, AND state is out, then ...".

Comment: maybe an easier hint: `else if` isn't something "special", it's just an `else` and an `if`…

Comment: @user10139530 I'd say there are better learning resources nowadays. In your example, the signature of `main()` isn't one of those the language standard defines ...

Comment: K&R and the programming style shown in that book is really from another era (and so is the C dialect that's being used). Probably not the best book to start learning C with in 2018.

Comment: @fvu what do you recommend me?

Comment: "C Traps and Pitfalls" by Andrew Koenig. The book is quite old as well so it does not list a lot of freshy discovered traps though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different tests being done here.

The first test is to see if the next character is specifically a newline; if it is, then we increment `nl` (which keeps track of the number of lines).

The second test is to see whether we're "inside" or "outside" of a word (which in this program is defined as a sequence of non-whitespace characters).  If the next character is any whitespace character (including a newline), then we're "outside" of a word and set `state` to `OUT`.  Otherwise, if we're in the `OUT` state, then we need to change to the `IN` state and update the number of words.

It could be written a little more clearly as:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    ++nc;
    /**
     * Are we starting on a new line?
     */
    if (c == '\n')
       ++nl;

    /**
     * Are we inside or outside of a word?
     */
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
       state = OUT;
    else if (state == OUT) {
         state = IN;
         ++nw;
    }
```

That's why only one `else if` is used.

Comment: I don't understand if the program has to check all of those three if's or only the first one which is valid.

Comment: @user10139530: Don't know how I can make it clearer.  The first `if` is checked every time through the loop.  The second `if` is checked every time through the loop, and the `else if` is checked if `c` is not a whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

The second if-test must be done regardless of the outcome of the first if-test. Therefore there is no else attached to the second test. Perhaps a better way to write it would have been:

```
if ( (c == ' ') || (c == '\n') || (c == '\t') ) {
   state = OUT;
   if ( c == '\n' ) {
      ++n1;
   }
} else {
   state = IN;
   ++nw;
}
```

Using the isspace() function might make it more clear (assuming that is what is really desired):

```
if ( isspace(c) ) {
   state = OUT;
   if ( c == '\n' ) {
      ++n1;
   }
} else {
   ...
}
```